# Component not visible on the editor but visible in object inspector

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a form where several components are present, in the `Component Window Area` at the bottom of the visual editor.

However, one component is not visible there, allthough it is visible in the `Object Inspector`. There are other components of the same type present, they are all visible so I guess there is not a problem with the component itself.
Also there are no scrollbars visible in the `Component Window Area`

In other words, via the `Object Inspector` I can find the component, and set all its properties and so on, but I cannot see it on the form in the designer.

Any idea what can cause this ?
Everything still works but it has me worried that there is something wrong with my project...

I have compared the code in the Designer.cs with the other components that are visible, there is nothing different there and no code is missing.
I restarted VS
I tried `Clean` and `Rebuild` also no effect

I dont know what else I can still try

Comment: @LarsTech OK I will, I thought it was not appropiate to answer an own question

Comment: Quite the opposite.  See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix this, it seems the component had a negative `Left` property.

So first select the component using the `Object Inspector`
Then make the `Designer` active by clicking on its tabsheet
Now you can use the `Arrow keys` to move the component back into the visible range.

I always thought that components do not have a `Location` property, but aparently they do and for some reason it was messed up on this component.
In the Designer.cs there is no `Location` or `Left` property...

Comment: The "component" window should have had scrollbars to reach that missing component.  Also, if you right click the component window area, you can select "Line Up Icons" to put everything back in order.

Comment: Yes but in my case there where no scrollbars visible for some reason. I never knew about the `Line up` option, that would probably also solved it

Answer (score 1):

I had same subject and had resolved by going into {formobjectname}.Designer.cs code, then looking for the object definitions and changing this.{object}.location values.
In my case y value vas negative.
Regards.